# plot of DEM of Antarctica using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf

How to plot the Digital Elevation Model of Antarctica using python?

I tried to plot a netcdf file. but i didn't get a lats,lons overlayed plot.

I used this code...i want overlay latitude and longitude in this plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# Load DEM data
nc = Dataset("c:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\PYTHON\\BedMachineAntarctica-v3.nc")
lats = nc.variables['y'][:]
lons = nc.variables['x'][:]
elevations = nc.variables['thickness'][:]

# Create figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Set title and axis labels
ax.set_title('Antarctic Ice Surface Topography')
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')

# Create and show plot
im = ax.imshow(elevations, cmap='terrain', origin='lower', extent=[lons.min(), lons.max(), lats.min(), lats.max()])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post your code, what is the result, and how it doesn't meet your expectation?
Also, you may want to check rasterio library, like in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/spatial-data-science/digital-elevation-model-dem-in-python-758f0ede3af8)

Comment: You really need to provide details about the data and what you have attempted. It’s hard to provide an answer without even knowing what data format you are working with

Comment: I would suggest using `ax.pcolormesh` instead of `ax.imshow`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/plotting.html) for accessing NetCDF-based data sets. matplotlib and [cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/matplotlib/intro.html) are good for plotting xarray data sets.

Here is some example that can be used as a starting point:

```py
# import some modules
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.mpl.ticker as cticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# set the variable of interest
variable = 'cluster'

# load the data set
ds = xr.open_dataset('path/to/your/dataset.nc')

# create a figure
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8), dpi=300)

# create a projection 
ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())


# plot the data set
ds[variable].plot.pcolormesh(
    cmap='rainbow_r',
    ax=ax,
    add_colorbar=False
)

# define latitudes and longitudes
xticks = np.arange(-180,181,30)
yticks = np.arange(-90,90,30)
ax.set_xticks(xticks); ax.set_yticks(yticks)

# format the x and x ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(cticker.LongitudeFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(cticker.LatitudeFormatter())

# set the axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=14)

# set the title
ax.set_title('This is my plot', fontsize=16)

# show the coastlines
ax.coastlines()
```

[image: xarray cartopy plot]

Let me know If you need more explanations.

Comment: Thank you for your response .let me try this code.